# When does Indesign automatically update links after a rename or move?

Tags: adobe-indesign, file-placing

Sometimes I have to rename or move my linked files to another name or location, I can't remember my file were open or not but all I want to know is how and when it happens. Is there any option to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, InDesign will not auto-update renamed or moved links.

The proper way to handle this is to create a 'Links' folder next to your INDD source file and drop everything in there. Clearly, not the only way, but when working with long-term clients and multiple versions of the same job, its better to remove any doubt and just know by default every linked item is in the 'Links' folder and nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

InDesign will let you know if a file has been updated or if it is missing within the links panel, but will not tell you where a missing link has gone to. 
You can avoid this by packaging your file, this collects all links and fonts together within one folder, then if you move the project folder all associated files are moved alongside it.

Comment: It's weird... but sometimes while my indesign is open, when I move some links to another folder ... and then back to idesign i see that the path of them changed to that folder... but right now i can't remember what was the folder name so if it be "Links" could take an auto-rename!